# Find an element such that its order equals the cardinality of the group of cartesian product

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

I've been stuck on this question for quite some time and can't seem to be able to solve it (it's in my algorithms course).

> Consider the group: $$G = (\Bbb Z_6 \times \Bbb Z_8, \oplus)$$
>
> where: $$(a, b) \oplus (c, d) = (a+c \bmod 6,b + d\bmod 8)$$
>
> Find an element $a \in G$ such that: $${\rm ord}(a) = |G|$$

I have been able to find the identity element which I think is $(6,8)$, but I still don't understand how to calculate the order of an element in $G$.

Say I take an element like $(2,4)$, its order, if I'm not mistaken, should be the smallest integer $m$ such that $a^m=e$
How do I calculate $a^m$? I tried $(a,b)\oplus(a,b)$ but can never get $(6,8)$ (the identity element).

I can't find what I'm doing wrong, and I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: There are no such elements. If there were such an element, your group would be cyclic, but this group is not cyclic. The best you can do is an element of order $24$, but the gorup has order $48$.

Comment: The group here is *additive*, so you aren’t calculating $a^m$, you should calculate $ma$ that is, $a$ added to itself $m$ times.

Comment: Note that $(2,4)^n = (2n, 4n)$ in this group.

Comment: $(6,8)$ isn't the identity because $6$ and $8$ are not in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $\mathbb{Z}_8$, respectively. The identity would be $(0,0)$.

Comment: The identity element is $(0,0)$, (which is equal to $(6,8)$). You will **always** get the identity element by adding an element of this group to itself enough times. If you are never getting the identity, you aren’t doing things correctly. But because you don’t **show** us what you are doing, we cannot tell you what it is that you are doing wrong.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you so much, I feel stupid after thinking it was (6,8) haha. I will try again with $ma$

Comment: $(6,8)$ is the identity, as it is another name for $(0,0)$ @JakeBrown

Comment: Just to make sure I get this right, say $(2,3)^5$ is $(10,15)$? So I can calculate the order of an element by looking for the smallest power that gives me (0,0)? Because if so, the highest order I could find is 12, for example in $(1,7)^{12}=(12,84)=(12+12 \bmod 6, 84+84 \bmod 8)=(0,0)$, or is it $(10 \bmod 6, 15 \bmod 8)$ and then the highest order is 24 and the question can't be solved?

Comment: Don’t use multiplicative notation! This is an *aditive group*, so writing things like “$(2,3)^5$“ is just going to be confusing. $5(2,3) = (10,15) = (4,7)$.

Comment: $12(1,7) = (0,4)$; $84$ is not zero mod $8$, it is $4$ modulo $8$. The order of $(1,7)$ is $24$.

Comment: “$(12+12\bmod 6,84+84\bmod 8)$” is not equal to $12(1,7)$. It is equal to **twice** that; you are adding $(12,84)$ to $(12,84)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see, thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two groups and $G= G_1 \times G_2$ is the usual Cartesian product between them ( i.e $ (a,b) * (c,d) = (a\cdot c, b \cdot d)$, where the first $\cdot$ is operation in $G_1$ and the second in $G_2$), then order of any element $(a,b)$ in $G$ is least common multiple of order of $a$ in $G_1$ and order of $b$ in $G_2$.
In your case, order of element in $Z_6$ is a factor $x$ of 6 and order of any element in $Z_8$ is a factor $y$ of 8. For any such $x$ and $y$, least common multiple would be 24. But the cardinality of your group is 48. Hence no such element exists.